# @NonNull annotation in project Lombok

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I recently started to use `lombok` in my project. In lombok documentation, it is specified that `@NonNull` annotation can be configured to throw either `NullPointerException` or `IllegalArgumentException`. It is specified that by default `NullPointerException` will be thrown. It is also specified that to throw `IllegalArgumentException`, I should set `lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = IllegalArgumentException`. But, I am not understanding where I should specify `lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = IllegalArgumentException` in my code.
`

```
import com.sandesha.lombak.domain.Employee;

import lombok.NonNull;

public class EmployeeOperation {

/**
 * @NonNull performs null check
 * @param e1
 * @param e2
 * @return
 */

public boolean isEqual(@NonNull Employee e1, @NonNull Employee e2)
{
    return e1.equals(e2);
}
}
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a file named `lombok.config` in the home directory of your project, which is the default lombok configuration file to your project. The file looks like:

```
lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = IllegalArgumentException
lombok.nonNull.flagUsage = [warning | error]
```

You may see [the project](https://github.com/hypery2k/angular-spring-boot-sample/tree/master/angular-spring-boot-webapp)

Comment: Thank you it helped a lot. But, is there a way, wherein, I should be able to throw `NullPointerException` somewhere and `IllegalArgumentException` somewhere?

Comment: Yup. For this, you need to check it manually ( I didn't find another way). As like : `if (param == null) throw new NullPointerException("param");` But default is : `IllegalArgumentException` as you have set it already.

Comment: @SandeshaJ You could use multiple `lombok.config` files. For every package, there's a search starting in its directory and going up, so more specific settings override those in higher directories. But please, don't do it, stick with one exception. It doesn't matter much, but you're going to confuse yourself at best.

Answer (score 3):

This is not parameterized in the `@NonNull` annotation, it can be only specified in the Lombok [configuration keys](https://projectlombok.org/features/NonNull)  of @NonNull:

> Supported configuration keys:
>
> lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = [NullPointerException | IllegalArgumentException | Assertion] (default: NullPointerException).
>
> [...]

Create a `lombok.config` file in your project root directory, containing this line:

```
lombok.nonNull.exceptionType = IllegalArgumentException
```

More details about the Lombok configuration system are in the [Lombok documentation page](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration).